# How do I create a JSON from a TEXTAREA based on line-breaks?

Tags: jquery, json, textarea

I want to parse a TEXTAREA, putting each line into a JSON array via jQuery. Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just like this:

```
var array = $('textarea').val().split(/\n|\r/);
```

So you'll get JavaScript array object, not JSON string. If you want JSON string you can use [jquery-json plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/) and then do the following:

```
var jsonString = $.toJSON( $('textarea').val().split(/\n|\r/) );
```

And if you want object, not array encoded in JSON do that:

```
var o = {};
$( $('textarea').val().split(/\n|\r/) ).each(function(i){
   o[i] = this;
});   
var jsonString = $.toJSON(o);
```

Comment: This is an array. I want JSON with the key being the line number